# Trouble with connecting R to MySQL database using tcpl R package

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have a database stored in MySQL and need to connect to it in R using the tcpl R package.

I tried connecting using the following:

```
tcplConf(user='root', password= YOUR_PW, db='prod_internal_invitrodb_v4_1', drvr='MySQL', host='localhost')
```

This however keeps giving an error:
Error: Failed to connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

When I try connecting with dbConnect(), it works:

```
con <- dbConnect(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(), user='root', password=YOUR_PW, db='prod_internal_invitrodb_v4_1', host='localhost')
```

I don't think it's an authentication issue. Does anyone have some advice on how to resolve this establish a connection using tcplConf()?

Comment: The error message indicates you tried to authenticate without password. Take a look at the password parameter in tcplConf as either the parameter name is wrong or the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the connection issue with tcpl R package has been resolved. Because I had run and used RMySQL to establish a connection with the MySQL database, it was interfering with the authentication and establishing a connection using tcplConf().

```
unloadNamespace("RMySQL")
```

After this, I ran tcplConf() which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ater installing the driver

```
install.packages("RMySQL")

library(RMySQL)
```

your connection string must be like this

```
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                            dbname='prod_internal_invitrodb_v4_1',
                            host='localhost',
                            port=3306,
                            user='root',
                            password=YOUR_PW)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [tcpl documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/tcpl/man/config_funcs.html), it uses `pass` parameter to pass the password instead of the `password` parameter that you used:

> Usage

> tcplConf(drvr = NULL, user = NULL, pass = NULL, host = NULL, db = NULL, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, I'm getting another error now: 'Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'statement' in selecting a method for function 'dbExecute': no slot of name "Id" for this object of class "MySQLConnection"
Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
  no slot of name "Id" for this object of class "MySQLConnection"'

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you get another error, you need to another question! This second one us totally different from the current one and had nothing to do with mysql.